# Ipad screen resolutions and desktop versions

Tags: html, css

Why would this not work.

```
body{
    @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
        min-width:1339px;
    }
}
```

I want if the user is on an Iphone or Ipad 2 to set the min-width:1339px; but if on deskop browsers to not add any min-width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With media queries, you can't put them *inside of* a selector.

**Edit:** After re-reading, I also see that you want to apply this to iPads/iPhones, so you want max-width, not min-width.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        min-width:1339px;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I re-read and realized you want this to ONLY apply to mobile devices, instead of ONLY to desktop. But if you only want it to apply to devices smaller than 1024px, why set the min-width to a number higher than the width of the devices? Either way, try this updated code out and see if it does what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

bring it outside of the body tag:

`@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
        body { min-width:1339px;}
    }`

Answer (score 0):

In order to set this min-width measurement, the media query must have a ID or a class to modify. You must also enclose the measurement with curly brackets.

```
Example:

 @media screen and (min-width:1024px){
     body{min-width: 1339px;}
}
```

Don't put a space between the media query and the first curly bracket, because it will interpret the media query as invalid. Also, make sure to put all the styling in the out curly bracket, otherwise if you put it outside of the curly brackets, it will apply the styles to the entire page.

Hope that helps.

Updated:

I'm wondering if the width might be an issue, but before we jump to that conclusion. I think I found what you were missing. Try this, updated example:

```
    @media screen only and (min-width: 1024px) {
     body{min-width: 1339px;}
    }
```

If that doesn't work, I try editing the width. Because I believe since the min-width measurement will not display because it is larger than the minimum width of the iPad screen. If you try altering the width, I would set a base width:1339px; and then a max-width: 85%; and then work your way down from there. By doing so, that will use the width of 1339px and then scale it down to whatever percentage you specify for the iPad. It will make your layout responsive, which I believe from what I read is what you're trying to do.

Let me know if this works.